# SWIFT: keyNotFound Swift.DecodingError.Context error message

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I am trying to access the ProPublica API https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/members/ but am coming across this error message.

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "copyright", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"copyright\", intValue: nil) (\"copyright\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Here is what the json looks like:

```
    {
   "status":"OK",
   "copyright":" Copyright (c) 2019 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.",
   "results":[
      {
         "congress": "116",
         "chamber": "Senate",


         "num_results": 100,
         "offset": 0,
         "members": [
              {
                 "id": "A000360",
                 "title": "Senator, 2nd Class",
                 "short_title": "Sen.",
                 "api_uri":"https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/A000360.json",
                 "first_name": "Lama
```

It has much more I'm testing so I just want to extract the copyright.

Here is what my struct looks like:

```
struct LawData: Codable {
let copyright: String
}
```

Here is what my parsing looks like:

```
    protocol LawManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateStatus(_ lawManager: LawManager, law: PostModel)
    func didFailWithError(_ error: Error)
}

struct LawManager {
    
    // Create URL
    let urlSenateString = "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/bills/upcoming/house.json"
    
    // Creating the delgate member
    var delegate: LawManagerDelegate?
    
    // Calls API and sets the header.
    func fetchSenateUpcoming() {
        let urlHouse = URL(string: urlSenateString)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: urlHouse)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("PROPUBLICA_API_KEY", forHTTPHeaderField: Constant.APIKEY)
        
        performRequest(request)
    }

    func performRequest(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) {
        
        let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error!)
                print("No")
                return
            }
            if let safeData = data {
                if let post = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
                    self.delegate?.didUpdateStatus(self, law: post)
                }
            }

        }
        
        session.resume()

    }

    func parseJSON(_ lawData: Data) -> PostModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(LawData.self, from: lawData)
            let stat = decodedData.copyright

            let post = PostModel(status: stat)
            return post

        } catch {
            self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error)
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
```

I know there are similar questions out there but I checked those and it seems like what I have wrote seems corrected it doesn't seem to be an issue with my parsing based on other questions.

Thank you! All help is appreciated!

Comment: At the beginning of the `parseJSON` method insert `print(String(data: lawData, encoding: .utf8))` to display the received JSON. I guess you get some error JSON.

Comment: To go further on vadian asking for more details: "Here is what the json looks like:
" No, that's what you are supposed to receive according to the doc, right? But what if you real response wasn't that, because of an error, a change on the doc, etc. ? That's why vadian's asking to print the real received response.

Comment: Thank you so much for both of your help! After printing the message, I realized that I messed up the request setValue for my APIKEY which was why the request was invalid.